# detaching a chrome tab on catalina causes a jump to a different workspace

Tags: google-chrome, mission-control

It is my habit to have dozens of chrome tabs open across a dozen workspaces in macOS.
Often I want to to re-organize these tabs.
For example, I may have an instance of chrome on workspace 5 with 10 tabs.
Let's say that I want to detach 3 of these to a separate instance of chrome on the same workspace.

This has worked fine for years. However, after the upgrade to macOS Catalina, when I detach the first tab, I and the tab are forced to a completely different workspace containing a completely different instance of chrome.
This is extremely disorienting and annoying and it happens every single time that I detach a single tab from an instance of chrome.

I've tried these commands in the terminal as suggested [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/339888/91429):

```
 $ defaults write com.apple.dock workspaces-auto-swoosh -bool YES
 $ killall Dock
```

But when I detach a tab now, the tab just seems to disappear.
It is actually transported to one of my 12 workspaces but I am not.
Now I have to go searching for it.

This is driving me insane.
Anyone have a work-around?

**UPDATE: I've confirmed this is a bug in chrome not macOS mission control**

This is so annoying that I switched to firefox and firefox does NOT experience the same issue.

Comment: Link to the bug Alex opened: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1062493

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I do get "teleported" with my tab, but that is also super annoying. Ordinarily I want the tab on the same desktop, that's why it was in that browser window in the first place.

Comment: This bug is apparently fixed in version 85.0.4182.0. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1062493#c36

Comment: Thanks @AlexRyan it's still happening on both my desktops, but not my laptop, so maybe there's some bad interaction with some setting that still has the bug :-/