# Apps don't gain focus when switching between them in Mission Control with a touchpad

Tags: macos, catalina, trackpad, spaces, mission-control

I have this weird issue where if I switch between two apps with a trackpad they do not gain focus and I have to click the app to start working in it.

Note that, by "switching between apps", I mean switching between 2 "desktop spaces" in Mission Control, one desktop space having just 1 app open at a time.

This is super annoying as it is way more convenient to, for example, be able to just press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab in Chrome instead of having to click the app and then press <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>. This issue is reoccurring, I've had times when it went away and then came back again.

Or am I just imagining stuff? It may just be that I never noticed this, but I would definitely remember being annoyed by something.

Comment: Yes it happens sometimes.. I just click in the dock to get focus. Or use cmd + tab in the first place.

Comment: I have the same issue, has anyone solved it yet.

Comment: @Re9iNee sadly it solved itself so I still have no answer for this; but the good news is that it hasnt appeared eversince

Comment: I have the exact same issue on Monterey. Sometimes it's working, other times it's not. It's very annoying...

Comment: Try this workaround: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/455387/217473

Answer (score 1):

### I somehow found a solution.

so previously I'd restart my Mac and that would solve this problem.
but I didn't want to restart it.

The Solution I came up with is to use `Log Out` instead of restarting. This is way faster than Restart and its not annoying.

Comment: There is a better way which is to "sleep" your computer instead of "log out"

Comment: putting my computer to sleep couldn't solve the problem since it saves the current session and nothing gets 'load' again.

Comment: Did you push your power key to get into sleep? Have you check the "sleep" item in menu of top left corner?

Comment: yes I did, logging out will solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the app on "Desktop 2" always gain focus when switching to "Desktop 1".
I somehow fixed it by creating "Desktop 3" and removing "Desktop 1"...
Not sure if it is fixed permanently though.

Comment: This technique worked for me on two separate machines. Was plagued by this issue for months. Delete all spaces/desktops and re-create them. As expected, Chrome windows (and other apps?) now receive focus when switching desktops. Finally! Thanks for finding the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the reason for me which is the app BTT caused the issue. I uninstalled it and reinstalled, then I haven't meet that yet.